# Why is my Sum query breaking my Loop?

Tags: php, pdo, sum

I have a loop that iterates through a table and displays the customer ID.
It works fine.  At the top of the loop it sets a variable to be equal to the customer ID and then echos it to the screen.  If there are seven items in the table it displays seven OrderIds.

However, if I then try to use that Customer ID to execute a sum statement the program displays the results the first time through but then quits without an error after the first iteration, instead of looping through, almost as if the recordset was being destroyed.

I am at a complete loss to understand why.  The code is below.  Many thanks in advance:

```
include ("../Connections/PDOConnection.php")

$Query= "
SELECT distinct
    OrderID,
    CustID,
    Name
FROM
    dbo.JNO_OrderHeader
WHERE
    CustID is Not Null 
";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($Query);

if ($stmt->execute()) {

    while ($Order=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $OrderID = $Order['OrderID'];
        echo "<br>OrderID: " . $OrderID;


        $Query1 = "SELECT SUM(dbo.JNO_OrderDetail.ExtendedPrice) AS TotalOrderPrice 
                   FROM dbo.JNO_OrderDetail 
                   WHERE dbo.JNO_OrderDetail.OrderId = :OrderID";

        $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($Query1);
        $stmt1->bindValue("OrderID", $OrderID);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $OrderTotal=$stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    

        echo "<br>Totals for order number ". $OrderID .": " . $OrderTotal['TotalOrderPrice'];
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you showing PDO errors? You cannot start a new query on the same connection until the previous one has returned all the rows? Maybe 'fetchAll' will be useful? Hmm, what database are you actually using? I assume 'mysql'. Whatever, it is worthwhile checking?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: That explains it entirely.  I need a new connection!  Thank you thank you!

Comment: Plus, I don't see anything defined for `$Order`.

Comment: Ah, another happy ending then.

Comment: *"I need a new connection!"* - what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

As people are saying, what is the error?

At a glance it might be the reuse of `$pdo`, try `$pdo1` like you did on the other variables in the loop.

Anyway, the looping and issuing multiple SQL statements like that is not optimal.  Consider a join and doing something like this?

```
SELECT
    oh.OrderID,
    oh.CustID,
    oh.Name
    SUM(od.ExtendedPrice) AS TotalOrderPrice
FROM
    dbo.JNO_OrderHeader oh
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.JNO_OrderDetail od ON od.OrderId = oh.OrderID
WHERE
    oh.CustID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    oh.OrderID,
    oh.CustID,
    oh.Name
```

Comment: Another option would be a subquery - `select some_columns, (select something_else from other_table) as extra_column from first_table`. Depending on the data it may be faster, or slower!

Comment: Depends of course but,  at least in my experience with MySQL, a subquery is almost never the more performant option.