# PHP issue... output stops after loop

Tags: php

ive got this code and somehow it stops after the first entry even though there should be way more.
If i take both foreach loops out, its doing fine. So the issue should be there but im either blind or stupid :(

```
    // Main Agenda
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
SELECT 
agenda.id, 
agenda.title, 
agenda.timeStart, 
agenda.timeEnd, 
agenda.description, 
agenda.speakers, 
agenda.moderators, 
agenda_locations.name,
agenda_days.dayDate,
agenda_categories.name
FROM agenda
LEFT JOIN agenda_locations ON agenda.location = agenda_locations.id
LEFT JOIN agenda_days ON agenda.dayDate = agenda_days.id
LEFT JOIN agenda_categories ON agenda.category = agenda_categories.id
WHERE agenda.active = '1'
AND agenda.deleted = '0'
ORDER BY agenda.timeStart ASC
");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($agendaId, $agendaTitle, $agendaStart, $agendaEnd, $agendaDescription, $agendaSpeakers, $agendaModerators, $agendaLocation, $agendaDate, $agendaCategory);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $speakersText = "";
    $moderatorsText = "";

    if( strlen($agendaSpeakers)>0 ){
        foreach(explode('###', $agendaSpeakers) as $speakerId) {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
            SELECT 
            name
            FROM speakers
            WHERE id = ?
            ");
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $speakerId);  
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($speakerName);
            $stmt->fetch();

            $speakersText .= $speakerName.", ";
        }
        $speakersText = substr_replace($speakersText, "", -2);
    }
    if( strlen($agendaModerators)>0 ){
        foreach(explode('###', $agendaModerators) as $moderatorId) {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
            SELECT 
            name
            FROM speakers
            WHERE id = ?
            ");
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $moderatorId);  
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($moderatorName);
            $stmt->fetch();

            $moderatorsText .= $moderatorName.", ";
        }
        $moderatorsText = substr_replace($speakersText, "", -2);
    }


    $var0 = $agendaId;
    $var1 = stripslashes($agendaTitle);
    $var2 = strtotime($agendaStart);
    $var3 = strtotime($agendaEnd);
    $var4 = stripslashes($agendaDescription);
    $var5 = $speakersText;
    $var6 = $moderatorsText;
    $var7 = $agendaLocation;
    $var8 = strtotime($agendaDate);
    $var9 = $agendaCategory;
    $agendaMain[] = array ($var0,$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7,$var8,$var9);
}
```

Comment: Think I saw someone ask this an hour ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443232/why-is-my-sum-query-breaking-my-loop/33443405#33443405

Comment: You really shouldn't be storing a list of ID's in a database field separated by `###` strings. Using a normalized table design (a few more tables in your case to link everything together), you could get the desired information in 1 or 2 queries instead of running queries in loops.

Comment: hey, why should i not be doing this exactly? its a field where max 5 ids are stored in...

Comment: It makes searching for specific information practically impossible and you are running a lot more database queries than necessary.

Comment: @ficuscr - its not event close to be the same issue. So better read before downvoting.

Comment: @jeroen thats true but not neccessary in this case. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @jQuery You assume a lot.  Same issue, reusing variable in loop.  Anyway,  I'm glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename you `$stmt` variable in your foreach loops.

Comment: @jQuery Then please accept my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: had to wait 5 min before doing so haha ;-)